# Java EE first cup maven error

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-7, netbeans-8

I'm trying to learn Java EE 7 with the updated version (7.0.5) of First cup example. I tried installing the archetype but I get the following error when building firstcup-war:

```
WARNING: Error injecting: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org codehaus/plexus/interpolation/ValueSource
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2658)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2007)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:629)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:831)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:758)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:255)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:204)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:954)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:987)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:950)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:217)
at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:45)
at org.sonatype.guice.bean.inject.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:53)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:128)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:259)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:217)
at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:45)
at org.sonatype.guice.bean.inject.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:53)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:128)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:259)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:108)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1011)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

I don't really know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I did some search and found the solution. The plexus-interpolation.jar file was corrupted. In fact almost all my dependencies were corrupted. I deleted them and re-downloaded them with maven.